# Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js in Angular app in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, zone.js

Im using angular 9 application, on-load of the app Im getting this error in IE11.
Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js.
And Component doesn't load and shows the above error in console.
I tried adding import 'zone.js'. But it didn't work.
Also, tried adding  in index.html file. But no luck.
This issue happens only in IE11. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: Have you tried to run `npm install --save zone.js`? If it still can't work, please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue so that we can have a test and have a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When we import zone.js in index.html, it works fine.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.8.19/zone.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load libraries as mentioned before:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39593160/10659482

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Akif, tried this earlier. Didn't work for me. :/